# как в label вывести сумму двух label в delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Суть в том, чтобы в label1 отобразилась сумма двух других label. Проблема в итоговой сумме label1

```
var
begin
  ADOQuery:=TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  ADOQuery.Connection:=dm.conadoc;
  ADOQuery.Close;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT Sum(tarif) as tarif FROM reester where len(tarif)>0;');
  ADOQuery.Open;
  lbl2.Caption:=floattostr(ADOQuery.fieldvalues['tarif']);

  ADOQuery:=TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  ADOQuery.Connection:=dm.conadoc;
  ADOQuery.Close;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT Sum(taksa) as taksa FROM reester where len(taksa)>0;');
  ADOQuery.Open;
  lbl3.Caption:=floattostr(ADOQuery.fieldvalues['taksa']);

lbl1.Caption:=floattostr(strtofloat(lbl2.Caption)+floattostr(strtofloat(lbl3.Caption))); 
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lbl1.Caption := FloatToStr( StrToFloat(lbl2.Caption) + StrToFloat(lbl3.Caption) );
```

Comment: Все получилось спасибо большое за помощь))

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее будет сначала посчитать сумму, а потом выводить её, примерно вот так:

```
begin
  ADOQuery:=TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  ADOQuery.Connection:=dm.conadoc;
  ADOQuery.Close;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT Sum(tarif) as tarif FROM reester where len(tarif)>0;');
  ADOQuery.Open;
  tarif := ADOQuery.fieldvalues['tarif'];

  ADOQuery:=TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  ADOQuery.Connection:=dm.conadoc;
  ADOQuery.Close;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT Sum(taksa) as taksa FROM reester where len(taksa)>0;');
  ADOQuery.Open;
  taksa := ADOQuery.fieldvalues['taksa'];

  lbl1.Caption := floattostr(tarif + taksa); 
  lbl2.Caption := floattostr(tarif);
  lbl3.Caption := floattostr(taksa);
end;
```

А еще правильнее, посчитать все сразу в одном SQL-запросе и получить 3 цифры сразу (с учетом возможности наличия NULL).